# Cookies not add in browser

Tags: asp.net-mvc, cookies

i want to set cookies value,but i can set value in expire time, there is some error. 
[image]

```
public string Ckey(string API)
    {
        //Create a Cookie with a suitable Key.
        HttpCookie KEY = new HttpCookie("ucsr");

        //Set the Cookie value.
        KEY.Values["ucsr"] = API;

        //Set the Expiry date.
        KEY.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(7);

        //Add the Cookie to Browser.
        // this is error line on run mvc project
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add(KEY);
        return API;
    }
```

Comment: Could you share the error message to give us the best chance of helping you out, thanks.

Comment: Now see image above

Comment: For some reason you don't have a valid `HttpContext` at that point, perhaps create the cookie in the model but pass it to the controller to set.

Comment: did you means `httpcontext` not working in model. other option for use cookies function anywhere

Comment: Well, it can but given your error it is not working in the model.Is the method being called while serving up a response i.e. from a controller action?